# If a simple write is done inside a synchronized block , then a read in another synchronized block is consistent?

Tags: java, multithreading, synchronized

The value written to a variable by one thread and other thread reading it in case both the operations are enclosed within synchronized blocks but both defined on different objects as below.

```
private Object o1 = new Object();
private Object o2 = new Object();
private int x = 0;
...
synchronized(o1){
    x = 10;//write (simple atomic write) inside the synchronized block so value is flushed to main memory 
}
...
synchronized(o2){
     System.out.println(x);// read inside the synchronized block so read from main memory and not from thread cache.
}
```

Q1. Is it guaranteed that read is consistent with the latest value of x ?

Another case

```
private Object a = new Object();
private Object b = new Object();
private int p = 0;
...
synchronized(a){
    p = p + 1;
}
....
synchronized(b){
    System.out.println(p);
}
```

Q2. As the  `p = p+1` is not atomic hence we may have data inconsistencies in this case. But for the Q1. case as the write is simple and atomic an done in synchronized block hence in that case we have consistency.

Please help me if my understanding is correct.

Comment: What does "latest value of x" mean? Latest measured how? There's no common reference to the two pieces of code so neither comes before or after the other in any defined order.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Q1. Is it guaranteed that read is consistent with the latest value of x ?

No, because they are synchronized on different things.

There is a happens-before relationship between the end of a synchronized block and the start of a block synchronized on the same monitor.

There is no such relationship if the monitors are different.

You can find this in the language spec [JLS 17.4.5](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se14/html/jls-17.html#jls-17.4.5) (emphasis mine):

> It follows from the above definitions that:
>
> - **An unlock on a monitor happens-before every subsequent lock on that monitor.**
> - A write to a volatile field (§8.3.1.4) happens-before every subsequent read of that field.
> - A call to start() on a thread happens-before any actions in the started thread.
> - All actions in a thread happen-before any other thread successfully returns from a join() on that thread.
> - The default initialization of any object happens-before any other actions (other than default-writes) of a program.

---

> Q2. As the p = p+1 is not atomic hence we may have data inconsistencies in this case. But for the Q1. case as the write is simple and atomic an done in synchronized block hence in that case we have consistency.

You don't have consistency. See answer to Q1.

Answer (score 0):

The `synchronized` block, in addition to locking, ensures that the values that are read inside are relevant and taken from the main memory, and even before the block is released, all the changed data will be transferred to the main memory.